# Md5 mix with upper and lowercase

Tags: php

How can I generate md5 string with upper and lowercase letter?
for example: TyUTExUM3Dw

What I’ve tried

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$key = "SecreTkEy";
$hash = md5($id.$key);

echo $hash;
```

Comment: First, MD5 hashes are only `0-9a-f`. Second, the MD5 hash only uses lower case characters. So, if you want mixed case you will have to do it yourself. We can give you a better answer if you tell us what you intend to use it for.

Comment: This question might be of interest to you. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/why-do-people-still-use-recommend-md5-if-it-is-cracked-since-1996

Comment: by re-writing the MD5 algorithm.. why do you want to do this?

Comment: if you just want a random string, matching to your requirements, don't use md5

Comment: (This comment is in response to the comments given here, not the question.)

A MD5 hash is a 128-bit sequence. A sequence of bits can be represented in any way imaginable; e.g. by "TyUTExUM3Dw" or by a smiley face. Saying that a MD5 hash is only represented as a hexadecimal is wrong. Also, saying a hexadecimal only uses lowercase characters is wrong.

The MD5 algorithm does not need to be re-written to procedure an output like "TyUTExUM3Dw". The MD5 algorithm produces a 128-bit sequence and nothing more; the encoding of the 128-bit sequence has nothing to do with the algorithm.

Answer (score 21):

1. The string "TyUTExUM3Dw" is not an MD5 hash, nor anything close to one.

   - An MD5 hash is a *number*, and is usually written in hexadecimal which uses 16 digits represented by `0-9` and `A-F`.
2. Casing is not important.

   - The hashes `b529d8871187ecc7fe5f152142b3440a` and `B529D8871187ECC7FE5F152142B3440A` are *exactly* the same.

What is the *end goal* you're trying to accomplish with your code? If you tell us that we can probably give you a better method to accomplish that.

Comment: No they are not. i had the same problem with uppercase it didnt work. but with lower case it worked. Check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083909/md5-hashing-casing-issue

Comment: @CadeLewis then whatever hashing lib you're using is needlessly case-sensitive. Hexadecimal is categorically case-*insensitive*.

Comment: `The string "TyUTExUM3Dw" is not an MD5 hash, nor anything close to one.` Incorrect. How to make this statement correct: `The string "TyUTExUM3Dw" is not an MD5 hash under any common encoding.`